# Can I say "what's up" or "what the heck is going on" to a teacher?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to know how provocative are the expressions in the title. I would like to say something similar, but not in a provocative or offensive way, since I would say it to a college's serious English teacher. By the way, do they have a different meaning?

Comment: Be much more specific about the context. Just what are you trying to ask the teacher, in what context?

Comment: Actually would be the presentation of myself, where all the classmates can see it.

Comment: Not clear, sorry. Try using more words.

Comment: @Drew What's not clear? There's a forum, where I have to write something about myself and where all my classmates can see it. But the author of the question is actually my serious English teacher. I do not understand why you cannot understand what I am saying, I am using english words...

Comment: What is it that you mean to ask by saying *What's up?* Are you asking your teacher what just happened? what's going on in general? Just what is your question for your teacher? You are using English words, but if you want people to help you understand whether some expression is appropriate in some context then you will help yourself by telling us what it is you are trying to say and how formal the context is. (Or take your chances that someone will guess well.) What kind of English class? Those questions are informal and familiar, but depending on the class and relations with your teacher...

Comment: Cell, I think @Drew wants to know when you will say it. Are you speaking teacher in the hallway before class? Are you just telling everyone about yourself? Do you have to submit something in writing? Is this an assignment, or a natural conversation? I think you are speaking about yourself, in an assignment, not a natural conversation, and the product is not written down. Am I right?

Comment: I would recommend *not* using these. Say, "Good morning. How are you?" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a teacher, and I run a relatively relaxed high school class.

"What's up?" - This sounds a little informal to me. I'd personally prefer a "good morning" or something similar.

"What the heck is going on?" - As a teacher, I would not want to hear this. It would make me think, at least for a second, that the students were very confused about what they should be doing, and that would make me unhappy.

For your second question, yes, they can have a very different meaning. "What's up?" is pretty much always an almost meaningless greeting, like "How are you?" but much less formal. People might answer the actual question, or they might just acknowledge that you greeted them. "What the heck is going on?" on the other hand, could be a very friendly, very informal greeting, but in the wrong tone of voice, it can be an offended comment on how chaotic things are: "We were having a great time, dancing and turning up the music, when the R.A. burst in and yelled 'What the heck is going on?'"

Comment: It may depend on whether 'What the heck is going on?' is said *to* you *about* you, or whether it is said *to* you about *someone or something else*. For example, if there's a commotion of some sort outside the classroom, a student might well ask you 'What the heck is going on (outside)?'.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, this is a *college* class and your English teacher is *serious*, then you might not want to use these quite familiar and informal expressions.

On the other hand, if the class and teacher are informal, and especially if the teacher is teaching you such expressions, then it might not be bad at all to practice them in this context.

It is hard to judge such things based on skimpy background. Try it, and see what happens! ;-)